# C++ - Deal with floating point errors in geometric interpolation

Tags: c++, floating-point

**Problem**

I am writing a ray tracer as a use case for a specific machine learning approach in Computer Graphics.

My problem is that, when I try to find the intersection between a ray and a surface, the result is not exact.

Basically, if I am scattering a ray from *point O*  towards a surface located at *(x,y,z)*, where z = 81, I would expect the solution to be something like *S = (x,y,81)*.
 The problem is: I get a solution like *(x,y,81.000000005)*. 
This is of course a problem, because following operations depend on that solution, and it needs to be the exact one.

**Question**

My question is: how do people in Computer Graphics deal with this problem? I tried to change my variables from `float` to `double` and it does not solve the problem.

**Alternative solutions**

I tried to use the function `std::round()`. This can only help in specific situations, but not when the exact solution contains one or more significant digits. 
Same for `std::ceil()` and `std::floor()`.

**EDIT**

This is how I calculate the intersection with a surface (rectangle) parallel to the *xz* axes. 
First of all, I calculate the distance `t` between the origin of my Ray and the surface. In case my Ray, in that specific direction, does not hit the surface, `t` is returned as 0.

```
class Rectangle_xy: public Hitable {
public:
    float x1, x2, y1, y2, z;
    ... 

    float intersect(const Ray &r) const { // returns distance, 0 if no hit
        float t = (y - r.o.y) / r.d.y;      // ray.y = t* dir.y
        const float& x = r.o.x + r.d.x * t;
        const float& z = r.o.z + r.d.z * t;
        if (x < x1 || x > x2 || z < z1 || z > z2 || t < 0) {
            t = 0;
            return 0;
        } else {
            return t;
        }
    ....
    }
```

Specifically, given a Ray and the `id` of an object in the list (that I want to hit):

```
inline Vec hittingPoint(const Ray &r, int &id) {
    float t;                             // distance to intersection
    if (!intersect(r, t, id))
        return Vec();
    const Vec& x = r.o + r.d * t;// ray intersection point (t calculated in intersect())
    return x ;
}
```

The function `intersect()` in the previous snippet of code checks for every Rectangle in the List `rect` if I intersect some object:

```
inline bool intersect(const Ray &r, float &t, int &id) {
    const float& n = NUMBER_OBJ; //Divide allocation of byte of the whole scene, by allocation in byte of one single element
    float d;
    float inf = t = 1e20;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((d = rect[i]->intersect(r)) && d < t) { // Distance of hit point
            t = d;
            id = i;
        }
    }

    // Return the closest intersection, as a bool
    return t < inf;
}
```

The coordinate is then obtained using the geometric interpolation between a line and a surface in the 3D space:

```
Vec& x = r.o + r.d * t;
```

where: 
`r.o`: it represents the ray origin. It's defined as a r.o : Vec(`float a, float b, float c`) 
`r.d` : this is the direction of the ray. As before: r.d: Vec(`float d, float e, float f`).
`t`: `float` representing the distance between the object and the origin.

Comment: [Handy reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

Comment: you cannot avoid rounding error. How do you calculate the crossing points? Different formulas that have the same exact solution can have widly differing numerical stability

Comment: A couple of somewhat related readings: https://pbrt.org/fp-error-section.pdf and https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/1689468335601264/Its-Really-Not-a-Rendering-Bug-You-see....pdf

Comment: Sometimes, iterative procedures can help: in your case, if the obtained point is not on the surface exactly, you can perform a projection of this point to the surface. But as noticed above, we cannot be very helpful without more details

Comment: Instead of comparing for exact equality, it's common to use some reasonable epsilon (say 0.005 for example) and consider values as equal if they are within that epsilon of each other.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You have to be super careful when doing that though, to _never_ do that in something that requires a "strict weak ordering" like most standard algorithms or data structures.

Comment: A different approach (which may or not be useful to you) is that of [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/exact.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I updated my question, posting the relevant code that I use for to calculate the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon` for your float/double comparison. And see if your result is in the region +-epsilon.

An alternative would be to not ray trace towards a point. Maybe just place relatively small box or sphere there.